# shutdown computer at a particular time .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown

I'm trying to shutdown the computer using a BAT file on windows 7 and was wondering if anyone knew how to do it. Here's what I got so far (it doesn't work). Thanks in advance

```
@echo off
 :W
if %time% == 08:53:00 goto :Y
if %time% == 08:54:00 goto :X
goto :W

 :Y
taskkill /f /IM "iexplore.exe"
 :X
shutdown.exe /s /f /t 60 /c " Sleeeeeeeep "
```

Comment: Doing such a loop doesn't look like a good idea to me. Why not a scheduled task that executes your batch file?? Executing the shutdown file should be enough, that will kill IE as well.

Comment: BTW, if you run `echo %time%` in a console, do you get that exact format? Beware of leading spaces and seconds decimals.

Comment: Remove the colons **:** from the goto statements. Don't need .exe after shutdown. Otherwise that syntax looks good. And put a pause before goto W or you'll spend all but 2 minutes of your life inside that loop.

Comment: First: never build a loop without some idle time to avoid max CPU load. Second: `%time%` gives the time down to centiseconds (`10:23:46,72`), which will *never* exactly match a time string with precision of seconds (`10:23:46`). Third: yes, a scheduled task is a much better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you want a .bat file? You can use powershell on Windows 7. Run this in the command prompt and there is no script file to worry about, just a scheduled task like @Andrew mentioned:

```
schtasks /create /tn "shutdown" /sc daily /st 08:53 /tr "powerShell -command { taskkill /f /IM iexplore.exe; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600; Stop-Computer -Force }"
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works well. you just put it correct time format. it properly works all other windows versions.

Example:

> %time%==00:00:0.00

I just modify your time format and run on my computer it perfectly works it.

> only you put it 24 hours time format

```
@echo off
:W
if %time% == 20:53:0.00 goto :Y
if %time% == 20:54:0.00 goto :X
goto :W

:Y
taskkill /f /IM "iexplore.exe"
:X
shutdown.exe /s /f /t 60 /c " Sleep... "
```